# How to make Sphinx prefer complex keywords to its parts

Tags: sphinx

We have two fields: keywords (weight 10) and text (weight 1).

Let's see three records:

A: keywords = "**some stuff**, happy cat", text = "This is A"

B: keywords = "where **stuff** is, **some** dogs", text = "This is B **some stuff**"

C: keywords = "where **some stuff** is", text = "This is B **some stuff**"

When searching for **some stuff** we want to have A record above the B and C.

Sphinx shows A below the others, because it has less mentions for the stuff. But A has exact match in keywords (comma really means), so it is the only right answer.

How to configure Sphinx to reach that? Any kinds of texts preprocessing are allowed.

Answer (score 1):

You can check various ranking modes as per your requirement.

Please see **SPH_RANK_SPH04** ranking mode, this should work as per your expectation
You should mention which version of sphinx you are using.

Please read more details on ranking modes [here](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/2.0.6/weighting.html)

Answer (score 0):

In your example C is most relevant.

You can filter by exact matches using quotes around search term.
You need to set matching mode to SPH_MATCH_MODE_EXTENDED2 which tell sphinx to get documents which containt exact string.

I recommend you take a look at [extended search syntax](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/manual-2.0.6.html#extended-syntax).